# Will disabling global maintenance mode of an ovirt cluster start an accidentally shutdown engine?

Tags: ovirt

Due to upgrading the ovirt self-hosted engine I had the cluster in `global maintenance mode`. I was not aware, that issuing `shutdown -r now` within the engine VM will in fact not reboot the engine, but will only make it shutdown. After reading the [engine troubleshooting guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_virtualization/4.1/html/self-hosted_engine_guide/troubleshooting) once again I now know better.

For reasons unknown the root password for the node the engine is running on, is unknown. Thus I cannot get into the node via shell or web interface.

So... If I'd deactivate the global maintenance mode on a different node of the cluster that is capable of running the engine by issuing a `hosted-engine --set-maintenance --mode=none`, would this trigger a restart of the hosted engine ?

The cluster is running ovirt 4.1.9.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own questions: Yes this is what will happen. When an ovirt cluster is in `global ha maintenance mode` and the hosted engine vm has been shut down, it can be started again by issuing this command on a node that is capable of running the hosted engine.

```
# hosted-engine --set-maintenance --mode=none
```

Give the system some minutes to gather its status. Then the engine should be up again.